# error unmarshaling JSON: while decoding JSON: json: unknown field "hostAliases"

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am using [PIVT](https://github.com/APGGroeiFabriek/PIVT) repo and following scaled up raft network but when i run

```
helm template channel-flow/ -f samples/scaled-raft-tls/network.yaml -f samples/scaled-raft-tls/crypto-config.yaml -f samples/scaled-raft-tls/hostAliases.yaml | argo submit - --watch
```

I get this error : -

```
Failed to parse workflow: error unmarshaling JSON: while decoding JSON: json: unknown field "hostAliases"
```

Answer (score 3):

After researching for few hours i found that it was a problem with my argo version i,e. earlier it was 2.2.0 and when i updated my argo to 2.4.2 by doing

```
sudo curl -sSL -o /usr/local/bin/argo https://github.com/argoproj/argo/releases/download/v2.4.1/argo-linux-amd64

sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/argo
```

It worked .